# ComponentKit Can't call super newWithView after subclassing CKCompositeComponent

Tags: ios, facebook, objective-c++, componentkit

.h file

```
#import "CKCompositeComponent.h"

@interface JWTextComponent : CKCompositeComponent

- (instancetype)newWithText:(NSString *)text;

@end
```

.mm file

```
#import "JWTextComponent.h"

@implementation JWTextComponent

- (instancetype)newWithText:(NSString *)text
{
    return [super newWithView:{
            [UILabel class],
            {
                {@selector(setText:), text},
              }
            } size:{}];
}
@end
```

But I get this error that I can't figure out why

[image: But I get this error that I can't figure out why]

in my Podfile I have simply,

```
target 'CKTest' do
pod 'ComponentKit', '~> 0.11'
end

target 'CKTestTests' do

end
```

I tried following the sample project as closely as possible, this seems like the most simple case of creating a CKComponent, but maybe some fundamental error, I can't seem to get it working.

Where is the big white elephant hiding in my blind spot?

Comment: If i replace super with CKComponent, I get the error incompatible pointer type

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

I didn't have the initialiser as a class initializer.

```
+ (instancetype)newWithT:(NSString *)text
```